# Reactions of Grignard Reagents with amides

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, grignard-reagent

Can Grignard reagents add to amides? It appears from the synthetic pathway shown below that there has been some form of nucleophilic substitution at the carbonyl group.

[image]

Source: 49th IChO Preparatory Problems, Task 29

Comment: I don't see why not...There's even a sort of electron sink - the benzyl ester - for the nitrogen...

Comment: I'm a bit more puzzled why the amide is cleaved and not the carbamate...

Comment: Grignard can certainly react with tertiary amides (eg Weinreb amides) but I'm more than a little surprised than the ester isn't attacked first and that the chirality is retained. Is there any mention of  an additional reagent?

Comment: @Waylander looked it up ([*Org. Lett.* **2004,** *6,* 1329](https://doi.org/10.1021/ol049631e)) it's Grignard + TMEDA in THF

Comment: @Martin-マーチン the reference above also says that premixing TMEDA and the Grignard prior to reaction with the substrate minimises the extent to which cleavage of the Cbz group occurs